# AngularJS - padded ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

i want to create a highscore list using `ng-repeat`.

The Player list looks like:

```
[
  {name: 'anton', score: 32},
  {name: 'rolf', score: 3},
  {name: 'max', score: 12},
  {name: 'mike', score: 49},
  {name: 'john', score: 25},
  {name: 'rui', score: 5},
  {name: 'wolle', score: 6},
  {name: 'run', score: 0}
]
```

In case `$scope.currentPlayer.score` is 12 the output array of ng-repeat should look so:

```
[
  {name: 'anton', score: 32},
  {name: 'john', score: 25},

  {name: 'max', score: 12},

  {name: 'wolle', score: 6},
  {name: 'rui', score: 5}
]
```

The object of the currentPlayer (name: 'max') should be placed in the middle with the **two** following entries above and below.

In html output I also need the index of the Player-List, that depends on the score.

how i tried:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in highscoreTable | orderBy: 'score*1' : true"
     ng-hide="<!-- relationship betw. currentPlayer.score and user.score -->">

  <span>{{$index + 1}}</span>
  <span>{{user.name}}</span>
  <span>{{user.score}}</span>

</div>
```

How can i achieve that 'padding' of two objects ? Is there a way to fix with an custom filter or do i need a scroll-bar ? Thanks

Comment: Need to sort your data and find index that contains score you want and filter array based on that index. Not something you can do in the view very simply, requires custom filtering

Comment: you can move `order` to js code, and get something like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/j08v0eT9aHD4tFLruEUI?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work if the `currentPlayer.score` is present in the players score list (replace `<p></p>`with your preferred padding.

```
<div ng-repeat="user in highscoreTable | orderBy: 'score' : true">
    <p ng-if="user.score === currentPlayer.score"></p>
    <span>{{$index + 1}}</span>
    <span>{{user.name}}</span>
    <span>{{user.score}}</span>
    <p ng-if="user.score === currentPlayer.score"></p>
</div>
```

See [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4JhG7uKa6UDT8E3j2TnT).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-class` to add a CSS class to specific elements and add the padding or whatever you want to do via this class.

```
<div ng-repeat="user in highscoreTable | orderBy: 'score*1' : true" ng-class="{'current-player' : user.score === currentPlayer.score}">

  <span>{{$index + 1}}</span>
  <span>{{user.name}}</span>
  <span>{{user.score}}</span>

</div>
```

See [CodePen](http://codepen.io/ChristophT/pen/QjxXmM)